# Why shouldn't this question be closed as unreproducible?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed a review audit on this question: [Eclipse 'Loading data for Android 4.4.2' all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631577/eclipse-loading-data-for-android-4-4-2-all-the-time) . I was going to mark it off-topic due to the lack of specific instructions for reproducing the problem reported. Is there a different standard for programming tools?

Comment: I think I'm just going to stop reviewing things.

Comment: I have no idea what that upvote means.

Comment: This might be a good example of why one should use caution when moderating unfamiliar topics - almost anyone who has done Android development has seen that message at some point, so calling it irreproducible is a little far-fetched from the perspective of the topic community.  Don't be afraid to use that "skip" button if you are unsure about something in your queue.

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be fairly reproducible.

- He mentions the versions of the tools he's using *(Eclipse Kepler SP2 and the latest ADT plugin)*.
- He mentions the error he gets and the frequency with which it occurs.

I suppose it would've helped to have an exact ADT version instead of "the latest", especially since the fix was to install an even laterer (the laterest?) version.

It apparently was enough information for a few people with experience with those tools to chime in and help him solve the problem.

---

Just a couple suggestions, based on my personal experience:

- If there's any doubt about whether I understand the technology being addressed in the question, I usually just skip it. What seems like not enough info to me may actually be enough for others.
- Fairly often, I click the question title to open it in a new browser tab, so I can see how the community voted, what kind of comments have been left, etc.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have realized that not tagged with my filter -> audit. I'm frustrated that, when I take time out of my day to try to clean up part of my favorite tag ghetto, I get rewarded with a spanking over what seems to me to be a reasonable difference of opinion.

Comment: I believe the superlative of "latest" is "most latest" :-).